# Как сделать невидимый курсор на всей странице

Tags: css, css3, веб-программирование

Напишите пожалуйста что нужно в вставить в код что бы на всей странице курсор был невидимым.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В файл CSS добавить:

```
body {
  cursor: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.style.cursor = 'none';
```